# Bookdown::gitbook rendering two-level lists to code blocks

Tags: list, pandoc, bookdown, gitbook

Following the Bookdown manual, I'm trying to create a two-level list for gitbook output. Bookdown says I should do this:

```
+ one
+ two
    + two-a
    + two-b
```

Which should look like

- one
- two

  - two-a
  - two-b

But instead Bookdown seems to be ignoring the + and seeing it as a code chunk because of the indent, and I get this:

- one
- two

```
two-a
two-b
```

If I just knit the chapter to HTML, the list renders properly. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which bookdown/pandoc version you're using this may have changed to align with CommonMark.

Try indenting it with only two spaces:

```
+ one
+ two
  + two-a
  + two-b
```

From the [current MANUAL](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#block-content-in-list-items):

> List items may include other lists. In this case the preceding blank line is optional. The nested list must be indented to line up with the first non-space character after the list marker of the containing list item.

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into this.